# Selector-question about simple DOM parser

Tags: php, dom, html-parsing

I'm using the PHP simple DOM parser for filling an HTML template; it seems there's no support for defining a corresponding parent element like:

```
$parent= $dom->find("div.myBox");  // parent element
$txt = $dom->find("input",$parent); // select all inputs from $parent
```

DO you have any ideas on how it could be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The find function works on all nodes, not just the root node. Hence you can do something like:

```
$parent = $dom->find("div.myBox");
$txt    = $parent->find("input");
```

Although in this case this would probably be better

```
$txt    = $parent->find("div.myBox input");
```

Answer (score 1):

If you mean [SimpleHtmlDom](http://sourceforge.net/projects/simplehtmldom/), this should do it for you.

```
$parent = $dom->find("div.myBox");  // parent element
$txt    = $parent->find("input"); // select all inputs from $parent
```

Use the parent as the object; that's how it gives context.